# Convert this javascript function into jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Could someone convert this plain javascript function to use jquery functions? Thanks!

```
move_object = function (from, to) {
    var i, // local variable
    childnodes_length; // number of child nodes 
    // test if "from" cell is equal to "to" cell then do nothing
    if (from === to) {
        return;
    }
    // define childnodes length before loop (not 
    // in loop because NodeList objects in the DOM are live)
    childnodes_length = from.childNodes.length;
    // loop through all child nodes
    for (i = 0; i < childnodes_length; i++) {
        // '0', not 'i' because NodeList objects in the DOM are live
        to.appendChild(from.childNodes[0]); 
    }
};
```

Comment: Sure. Any other things you'd like us to do?

Comment: Could you post your version of the JQuery code and let us know where you've got struck?

Comment: What this function do? Did you try jquery? Try these http://api.jquery.com/children/

Answer (score 3):

This should do it:

```
$(from).contents().appendTo(to);
```

**Live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/simevidas/YxcYC/